# Angular2/4 - model driven form - asynchronous custom validator not working

Tags: validation, asynchronous, angular2-forms

I've a problem getting a custom async validator to work. My approach is as follows.

**Component:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {User} from "./user";
import {EmailValidators} from "./emailValidators";

@Component({
    selector: '<userform></userform>',
    templateUrl: 'app/users/userform.component.html',
})    
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit{
    public myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            name: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
            email: ['', Validators.compose([
                <any>EmailValidators.emailFormat,
                <any>Validators.required
            ]), EmailValidators.shouldBeUnique], // Async validator
            address: this._fb.group({
                street: ['', <any>Validators.required],
                zipCode: ['']
            })
        });
    }
    // save() and other methods here...
}
```

**Validator Class:**

```
import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";

export class EmailValidators {
    static shouldBeUnique(control: FormControl) {
        console.log("shouldBeUnique called");
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (control.value == "m@m.de") {
                    console.log("shouldBeUnique TRUE");
                    resolve({shouldBeUnique: true});
                } else {
                    console.log("shouldBeUnique NULL");
                    resolve(null);
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
    }

    static emailFormat(control: FormControl) {
        var value = <string> control.value;
        var regX = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

        if (!new RegExp(regX).test(value)) {
            console.log("emailFormat: True", value)
            return {emailFormat: true};
        }

        return {emailFormat: null}; // if validation passes return should be null
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input
        id="email"
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="email"/>
    <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.email.errors.required"
         class="alert alert-danger">Email is required {{ myForm.controls.email.errors | json }}</div>
    <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.email.errors.emailFormat"
         class="alert alert-danger">Email Format should be something like 'yourname@some-domain.com' {{ myForm.controls.email.errors | json }}</div>
    <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.email.errors.shouldBeUnique"
         class="alert alert-danger">shouldBeUnique {{ myForm.controls.email.errors | json }}</div>
</div>
```

Required validator works fine, the custom `emailFormat validator` works fine as well, the `divs` are kicking in and out where they should and even the `shouldBeUnique validator` works if its implemented as a standard validator.

But it does not as implemented above. The static method `shouldBeUnique` from the validator class is not even called. So - I assume the problem is somewhere in the components `formGroup`/`formControl` part. Please help.

**Update**

After testing various Angular-Versions (currently CLI/ 4.1.3) I found the following Error in the console:

```
email: FormControl
    asyncValidator: function (control)
        arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context. at function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
        caller: (...)
```

**Update**

...actually the same error appears for sync-validators but these are working fine. While many tutorials give the impression that async validation in NG is an easy task I also read this: https://kahlillechelt.com/asynchronous-validation-with-angular-reactive-forms-1a392971c062

Confusing.